# A question about scope's channel affecting other

Tags: signal, oscilloscope, measurement

I have the Digilent's USB scope and when I couple different signals to Ch1 And CH2, the channels affect each other. I didn't observe this with another USB scope.

If both are coupled I get the following:

[image]

As you see the orange signal is affecting the blue.

But when I by change reduced the frequency of the scope from 100MHz to 50MHz this problem disappeared as follows:

[image]

I changed the setting see below(set the freq. from 100MHz to 50MHz):

[image]

Is this cross talk phenomenon? Can someone explain why could this be happening and why reducing the scope freq. removed(or lowered) it?

Comment: Does the user manual / specifications list the "crosstalk" at the various bandwidths?